# Using a viewmodel which ignores the properties from the model

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I'm using entity framework and MVC (both CORE if that matters) to make a site. Using the model and tying it directly to the view is fine all the CRUD actions work, everything is lovely.

I wanted to use a couple of pages to access the model so the site looked better, so split the controls out onto separate views and added a corresponding viewmodel for each, so my project looks like this

```
-Model
--CustomerModel
-ViewModel
--CustomerNameVM
--CustomerAddressVM
-View
--CustomerNameView
--CustomerAddressView
```

The CustomerModel has a number of properties

```
Forename
Surname
Address
Postcode
```

with Forename and Surname in the CustomerNameVM and Address and Postcode in CustomerAddressVM.   Surname is defined as `[Required]` in the model but not in CustomerNameVM which I believe is the correct way to do it.

I'm struggling to get the model loaded into the viewmodel and then trying to save it when I'm editing the address details in CustomerAddressView because it errors when I try and save as the viewmodel doesn't contain Surname (from the model), so it's null and therefore the `[Required]` criteria isn't being met.

I've tried a few methods of trying to get past this like :-

- Jeffrey Palermo's Onion Architecture
- Repositories
- domain models

amongst others which all end up with the same problem, I can't save the Address as the Surname is null.

How do I ignore validation criteria for the properties of the model that aren't being referenced in the viewmodel?
Or how do I load and reference only those properties of the model that are present in viewmodel?

## Edit

For those who keep asking for code, which codeset? I've tried 30 of them now, none of which do the job. Which one of these do you want? I'm trying to get a general idea of how this is supposed to work as none of the methods, documentation and associated examples function.

Here's a starter for 10, it's unlike the other 29 codesets but it's code and probably the shortest.
The controller

```
    [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Step2Address(int? id, [Bind("CustomerID,txtAddress,txtPostcode")] VMAddress VMAddress) {
    
            if (ModelState.IsValid) {
//the saving code
            }
            return View(VMAddress);
        }
```

the model

```
  public class clsCustomer {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int CustomerID { get; set; }
    
        public string Forename { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string Surname { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string Postcode { get; set; }
```

the viewmodel

```
  public class VMAddress {

    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }

    public string Address { get; set; }
    public string Postcode { get; set; }
}
```

the view

```
@model theProject.Models.VMStep2Contact

    <form asp-action="Step2Address">
        <input type="hidden" asp-for="ComplaintID" />
        <input asp-for="txtAddress"/>
        <input asp-for="txtPostcode"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
```

the context

```
  public class ContextCustomer : DbContext {
        public ContextCustomer(DbContextOptions<ContextCustomer> options) : base(options) {

        }
        public DbSet<clsCustomer> Customer{ get; set; }
    }
```

Clicking "Save" on the webpage calls the controller straight away, which hits the first line `if (ModelState.IsValid)` and as the Surname isn't set and is `[Required]` the ModelState is not valid so no save is attempted.

Comment: Can you provide more of the actual example of your code?  What is the controller action which attempts to save this data?  What data are you trying to save?  If you do indeed have an operation which requires saving a record with a null value then clearly that value should not be required in the first place.

Comment: Looks like you have to mark `Surname` specifically as unmodified, but that's hard to tell without seeing code.

Comment: The Surname is required overall at the model level, but as it's not being entered/edited/touched on the address page (because why would I need to put the Surname on the address page) I just need to ignore it.

I've got about 30 different projects, trying to achieve the same end using various combinations of methods within controllers, models, domain controllers, viewmodels and random other functions and techniques like IoC that don't do the job so I didn't want to muddy the waters.   I'm open to any way that works.

Comment: @GertArnold How would I mark it as unmodified?

Comment: @Dave: Without an actual example of what's causing the problem, all we can really offer is general advice.  Advice like "If your data requires a value, put a value there."  Or "If you have a valid case in which no value is available, don't make it required."

Comment: The actual example of what's causing the problem is that I'm trying to add the postcode to the record, but the Surname isn't in the Address viewmodel, but, as Surname *is* required by the parent Customer model, the model is invalid, so no save occurs.

Comment: I can't just "put a value in there" as the value was "put in there" on the previous page. I can't *not* make the Surname required on the parent Customer model as it's required.

Answer (score 0):

I don't actually understand what the problem is, and without code, it's impossible to say what you might be doing wrong. Generally speaking, you shouldn't have any issues since you're using view models.

A view model is, of course, not saved directly to the database, so it has to be mapped over to an actual entity class that you will be saving. In the case of an edit, you should retrieve all relevant entities from the database, map any posted values onto the appropriate properties on those entities, and then save those entities back to the database. If you're doing this, presumably, the customer model should *already* contain the `Surname` and other required properties, and you'd only be modifying/setting the address properties.

If you're doing a create, then, simply you can't just take address information. You need the name as well, so for this, you'd need to pass a view model that contains at least all required fields, such that you have all the information you need to actually save the entity.

If you're trying to do a multi-step form, where you collect all the information over multiple posts, then you simply must persist the posted data somewhere other than the database until you have enough of it to actually save an entity to the database. This is usually accomplished via `Session`/`TempData`.

Comment: How is it difficult to understand the problem? I can't save my viewmodel because it doesn't contain the Surname. So you're saying that onload I load the entire model then put a copy into a viewmodel of the relevant properties, then onsave I load the entire model again change the relevant parts of the model from the viewmodel (before doing a `modelstate.isvalid` check, then save the model? If so, what's the point of the viewmodel? Why not just use the model directly?

Comment: So viewmodels are only any use if you've got no required fields (or all of the required fields are in the first viewmodel)?

Comment: No. But I don't think you actually understand what a view model is or what it's for. There's two main purposes. First is overpost: you can limit the view model to a subset of properties that the user is allowed to manipulate. The second is for things that don't belong on an entity class but are necessary for a view: IFormFile, a list of SelectListItems, etc. You never save a view model to the DB directly, because then it would be just an entity.

Comment: Which is what I understood them to be for, the VM contains whatever you need from whatever the source, so your VM could contain the current user's login name to be displayed on the view as well as the part of the model that this view is related to, in this case the customer's address.

Comment: So the view sees has available to it all it needs and no more

Comment: Then, again, what's the confusion. All you say is that you can't save your view model, which of course you can't. What's the actual issue?

Comment: If you want me to rephrase the question, I can't save the properties which are in my VM as I don't have a required property from the model

Comment: I have a VM which contains some properties of a model (which is what they're supposed to be used for ???) but can't update the parent model

Comment: When trying to save what's been changed via the VM it fails because I don't have something from the model

Comment: And there again, either that required property should be part of an existing entity that you're simply modifying or *it should actually be on your view model, because it's a required thing the user needs to provide*. Again, what's the issue?

Comment: But the required field *has* been entered on a separate view

Comment: via a separate viewmodel (the relevant one)

Comment: It *is* in the entity (model) that I'm modifying, from page 1, the first view

Comment: Then you're talking about a multi-step form, and like I said in my answer, you must persist that in something like Session/TempData so you can retrieve it after the next post and save the entity with all the components it needs.

Comment: So, I get to the last page of the process, say, 10 steps, I've persisted the data from the first 9 steps by whatever means. I then need to put all 10 steps data into the model and save it at that point?

Comment: So, if I've got nothing in the viewmodels, but a subset of the properties of the model, they're providing nothing extra (like the users's name for display purposes) why use them? Why not just use the model directly or ignore the model until the final step.